# Trying to Perform Vtune Analysis Using Python 3.6

Tags: intel, intel-oneapi, intel-vtune, intel-python

I am created Tensor Flow (1.15.5) environment using python 3.6

Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz

OS：Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

```
import tensorflow as tf

w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(([2,3]),stddev=1.0,seed=1) )
```

I trying to run Intel Vtune Analysis in tensorflow environment.

```
vtune --collect hotspot python train.py
```

After using this command I am getting Error. How to fix this error.

```
vtune: Error: Valid setenv symbol is not found in the binary of the analysis target.
vtune: Error: Binary file of the analysis target does not contain symbols required for profiling. See the 'Analyzing Statically Linked Binaries' help topic for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting this error as you have an outdated end-of-life python version.
Please refer https://endoflife.date/python

Please try installing later versions i.e. 3.7 or more.

```
conda install python==3.7
```

The issue doesn't exist when tried with python 3.7 as shown below:

```
(tf) :~$ cat train.py
import tensorflow as tf
w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(([2,3]),stddev=1.0,seed=1))

(tf) :~$ vtune -V
Intel(R) VTune(TM) Profiler 2022.3.0 (build 624050) Command Line Tool
Copyright (C) 2009 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.

(tf) :~$ python -V
Python 3.7.0

(tf) :~$ python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
1.15.0

(tf) :~$ vtune --collect hotspots python train.py
vtune: Collection started. To stop the collection, either press CTRL-C or enter from another console window: vtune -r /home/jyothisvjames/r002hs -command stop.
WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:2: The name tf.random_normal is deprecated. Please use tf.random.normal instead.
vtune: Collection stopped.
```